# Variable not being seen in C# code

Tags: c#, variables, scope

Learning C# and hit a snag.

Why isn't the variable 'number' used here?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    static string labelText = "";
    static string number = "";

    public Form1()                                  
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void serialNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string number = this.serialNumber.Text;
    }
```

I keep getting a warning that field 'number' is assigned but not used.

Comment: Because you're not using it, you're just assigning it -- just like the error says.

Comment: It means what it says. You have assigned it but you are not using it anywhere. Its the compiler's way of saying you don't need to assign it if you are not going to use it.

Comment: You are masking your class variable in a local scope.

Comment: Because you are only assign a value to it (`string number = this.serialNumber.Text;`), but you never use it in any operation.

Comment: What is the purpose of these static fields?

Comment: Lots of fastest-gun-in-the-west answers being posted... We would all be much better off if prospective answerers took time to write something detailed and instructive. The race for being first is over, everyone lost.

Comment: @CodyGray Your comment is much more valuable than the answers..

Comment: @CodyGray Agree, I think this question is better answered by another question: 'what are you trying to achieve?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
static string number = "";

private void serialNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string number = this.serialNumber.Text;
}
```

to

```
private string number = "";

private void serialNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    number = this.serialNumber.Text;
}
```

Comment: It is still a class level field. I just said to update the lines to the code I wrote.

Answer (score 3):

`string number = this.serialNumber.Text;` this line creates a new string.

try this to avoid the warning

> public partial class Form1 : Form
>       {
>
> ```
> static string labelText = "";
> static string number = "";
>
> public Form1()                                  
> {
>     InitializeComponent();
> }
>
> private void serialNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     number = this.serialNumber.Text;
> }
> ```

Comment: Lots of you had the answer. I do want the static portion of the declaration, as far as I know. I want the latest value to be remembered for use in other parts of my code.

Answer (score 2):

`string number` declares a new local variable which hides the static member variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your `serialNumber_TextChanged` method you declare a **local** variable called `number`. So if that is your complete code you never actually assign anything to `Form1.number` apart of the static initialization.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what's happening: you are assigning a value to the variable `number`, and then you don't do anything with that variable.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the warning is valid, and relates to the `static` member, which, in fact, is assigned and never used.  The one in `serialNumber_TextChanged` is local to that method and by definition, different.

This:  "Why isn't the variable 'number' used here?"...I do not understand.

Comment: There's another `number` variable at class-scope that is being hidden by the local `number` variable. That's the other `number` variable he's talking about.

Comment: @CodyGray Probably, but that's what I'm asking OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the `string` in the instruction `string number = this.serialNumber.Text;`, which is declaring a new variable, different from the class field, despite having the same name. Remove the `string` modifier and the instruction will refer to the class field already declared.